# Android Custom Adapter with list view. - Won't return view?

Tags: android, listview, view

I'm having a problem with returning my view to a listview with my custom adapter.
This is what I have in my main class which extends ListActivity.

```
lv = getListView();
ListAdapater itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this,itemList)
lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
```

And here's what I have for my custom adapter named ItemAdapter:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newsItem;

public ItemAdapter(Context a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> item){
    super();
    this.context = a;
    this.newsItem = item;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = view;

    if(view==null){

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_layout,parent,false );
    }

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date); // date


    HashMap<String,String> nItem = newsItem.get(position);

    title.setText(nItem.get(MainActivity.TITLE));
    date.setText(nItem.get(MainActivity.DATE));

    //UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(thumb_image, nItem.get(MainActivity.IMAGE));

    return vi;
}
```

I'm not sure why this adapter does not return any view at all? I've tried it with a SimpleAdapter with the same data and it works. I need to create a custom adapter to handle image data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: remove if(view == null)

Comment: you `getCount()` returns `0` size which means no views.Change it to your list size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your adapter you return 0 value.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

change it to

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return item.size();
}
```

and in getView method change

```
 if(view==null)

to

if(vi==null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on count only your views will added to your listview, So change your `getCount()` method as

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return newsItem.size();
}
```

And change

```
if(view==null)
```

to

```
if(vi==null)
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return newsItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return newsItem.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return newsItem.get(i).hashCode();
}
```

and

```
if(vi==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsItem;

        public ItemAdapter(Context a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> item) {
            super();
            this.context = a;
            this.newsItem = item;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return newsItem.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return newsItem.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


            ViewHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_item_layout,null,false);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }


            holder.title.setText(newsItem.get(position).get(MainActivity.TITLE));
            holder.date.setText(newsItem.get(position).get(MainActivity.DATE));

            //UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(thumb_image, nItem.get(MainActivity.IMAGE));

            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView title;
            TextView date;
        }
}
```